# Unable to Pass Assertion Check [Creating custom transformer, scikit-learn]

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, assertion

Given data from

```
%%bash
mkdir data
wget http://dataincubator-wqu.s3.amazonaws.com/mldata/providers-train.csv -nc -P ./ml-data
wget http://dataincubator-wqu.s3.amazonaws.com/mldata/providers-metadata.csv -nc -P ./ml-data
```

And these context:
"We'll begin with columns in our DataFrame containing numeric and boolean features. Some of the rows contain null values; estimators cannot handle null values so these must be imputed or dropped. We will create a Pipeline containing transformers that process these features, followed by an estimator.

Note: When the grader checks your answer, it passes a list of dictionaries to the predict or predict_proba method of your estimator, not a DataFrame. This means that your model must work with both data types. For this reason, we've provided a custom ColumnSelectTransformer for you to use instead scikit-learn's own ColumnTransformer."

I've been tasked to complete the following code snippets.
But I've not been able to pass the assertion test. Attached below is my attempt:

```
simple_cols = ['BEDCERT', 'RESTOT', 'INHOSP', 'CCRC_FACIL', 'SFF', 'CHOW_LAST_12MOS', 'SPRINKLER_STATUS', 'EXP_TOTAL', 'ADJ_TOTAL']

class ColumnSelectTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        X.dropna(inplace=True)
        return X[self.columns].values()

simple_features = Pipeline([
    ('cst', ColumnSelectTransformer(simple_cols)),
])
```

to fulfil this assertion check

```
assert data['RESTOT'].isnull().sum() > 0
assert not np.isnan(simple_features.fit_transform(data)).any()
```

Would appreciate any help I can get, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to pass the assertion test because of

```py
 return X[self.columns].values()
```

The correct return statement should have been

```py
return X[self.columns].values
```